# What's the difference between Systems security and Information Security?

Tags: operating-systems

I'm trying to differentiate between the the three.

What is Systems Security?

What is Information Security?

What's the difference between Systems Security and Information Security?

I'm trying to understand the difference between these three security terms. I could not find much that strongly differentiate between the two. I did find a clear explaination on Network Security though. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I only see two terms, not three.

Comment: The third security term is Network Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System security : how easy is to break into a system and compromise it, thus having access to the information behind it (access from both inside or outside). Remember that on a system most things can be accessed by root/Administrator.
Information security: how do we best keep our information? Is it safe from disaster (geo distribution)/hardware failure(backups, raid, snapshots, etc)/ hackers(public exposure)/unintended uses (access policy)?
From this perspective, system security is just one aspect of the many that you have to account for when you talk about information security.